# Django cannot recognize package specified in application's __init__.py if i reorganize my applications to an apps folder

Tags: django, django-3.1

I have a Django3 project, let's say "blog". Typical folder structure for applications is:

```
/blog/
    /article/
    /users/
    ...
    blog/
         __init__.py
         asgi.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

I want to let the structure to be clean so I put all applications into a apps folder. So now the structure looks like the following:

```
/blog/
    apps/
         __init__.py
         article/
         users/
         ...
    blog/
         __init__.py
         asgi.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

I want to use signal function in article apps/application, so the files in article are

```
/blog/
    apps/
         __init__.py
         article/
             migrations/
             __init__.py
             admin.py
             apps.py
             models.py
             signals.py
             tests.py
             views.py
         users/
         ...
    blog/
         __init__.py
         asgi.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         wsgi.py
    manage.py
```

in apps/article/signal.py file:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify

from core.utils import generate_random_string
from apps.article.models import Article


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Article)
def add_slug_to_question(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and not instance.slug:
        slug = slugify(instance.content)
        random_string = generate_random_string()
        instance.slug = slug + "-" + random_string
```

in apps/article/apps.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'article'

    def ready(self):
        import apps.article.signals
```

in apps/article/**init**.py file:

```
default_app_config = "apps.article.apps.ArticleConfig"
```

if I restart my server, it shows the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'article'. Check that 'apps.article.apps.ArticleConfig.name' is correct.
```

I also tried several settings in apps/article/**init**.py file like:

```
default_app_config = "article.apps.ArticleConfig"
```

```
default_app_config = ".article.apps.ArticleConfig"
```

```
default_app_config = "blog.article.apps.ArticleConfig"
```

```
default_app_config = "apps.ArticleConfig"
```

```
default_app_config = ".apps.ArticleConfig"
```

All are not useful and keep throwing errors, what should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

changed
apps.py to

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.article'

    def ready(self):
        import apps.article.signals
```

works for me